# Microsoft Teams: Bot, Task modules, replyToId

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a bot in Microsoft Teams, that I am using the REST APIs for managing. I send a card with an invoke action as follows:

```
{
  type: "Action.Submit",
  title: "Run task",
  data: {
    msteams: {
      type: "invoke",
      title: "Run task",
      value: JSON.stringify({"key1": "value", "key1": "value"})
    }
  }
}
```

The button renders correctly, and sends the following body over HTTP POST when clicked:

```
{ 
  name: 'task/fetch',
  type: 'invoke',
  timestamp: '2020-08-14T05:01:40.651Z',
  localTimestamp: '2020-08-14T01:01:40.651-04:00',
  id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  channelId: 'msteams',
  serviceUrl: 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/',
  from:
   { id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
     name: 'Suchit Agarwal',
     aadObjectId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
  },
  conversation: { 
    conversationType: 'personal',
    tenantId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
  },
  recipient: { 
    id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    name: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
  },
  entities: [{ 
    locale: 'en-US',
    country: 'US',
    platform: 'Mac',
    type: 'clientInfo' 
  }],
  channelData: { 
    tenant: { id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' },
    source: { name: 'compose' } 
  },
  value: { 
    data: { 
      requestId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      taskUUID: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      type: 'task/fetch',
      viewType: 'run_task' 
    },
    context: { theme: 'default' } 
  },
  locale: 'en-US' 
}
```

Notice, however, that the message received is missing the replyToId. How can I get that back to the server so I can update the message that the card action came from, as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions#example-incoming-invoke-message

Thanks for your help.

Comment: We are not able to repro the issue on our side. when you click on button does it hit your bot code? If yes could you please check the reply to id in the turncontext.Activity?

Comment: Hi Nikitha, Thanks a lot for your response. Yes, clicking the button sends a POST call to the http endpoint for the bot. The body that I posted above is the full HTTP POST body when the button is clicked. Is there something that I should be sending when constructing the action? Surprisingly enough, if I set "type" inside "data.msteams" to "messageBack" when constructing the button, I do get the replyToId back in the HTTP POST body

Comment: Hi @Suchit, Are you calling  the API with bot authenticaiton token? Could you please confirm.

Comment: Hi Nikitha, Yes we are using a JWT Validator token to authenticate the calls to the bot.

Comment: We are not able to reproduce it on our end. Are you trying it teams scope or 1:1, Could you please confirm?

Comment: The user talks to the bot always in a DIRECT_MESSAGE scope. These are the permissions that the bot has: 'user.read.all', 'group.readwrite.all', 'offline_access', 
'directory.readwrite.all'

Comment: Nikitha, would it help for me to send an email or something, in  which case I can maybe share more information, or maybe we can even schedule a call to go over the issue?

Comment: Could you please send a mail to microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com

Comment: Just sent the email, thanks

Comment: We have a bug on this issue, the fix has been checked in and is rolling through our deployment rings. It should be available in production in the next couple of weeks.